# JS - Rock-paper-scissors Game (Global vs local scope)

Tags: javascript

is anyone can help explain why the game doesn't work if I make both var computer and var status as Global scope, but it works for var humanResult & computerResult?

```
var humanResult = 0;
var computerResult = 0;
var status = document.getElementById("status");
var computer = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1);

//Click on Rock, Paper, Scissors

document.getElementById('rock').onclick = clickRock;
document.getElementById('paper').onclick = clickPaper;
document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = clickScissors;

function clickRock() {
    // var computer = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1);
    // status = document.getElementById("status");
    console.log(computer);
    if (computer  == 1) {
    status.innerHTML = "You played rock. The bot played rock you tied. :|"
    };

    if (computer  == 2) {
        computerResult++;
        status.innerHTML = "You played rock. The bot played paper you lose. :(";
    };

    if (computer  == 3) {
        humanResult++;
        status.innerHTML = "You played rock. The bot played scissors you win. :)";
    }

    document.getElementById('humanScore').innerHTML = humanResult;
    document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = computerResult;
}
```

*I place whole set of code on codepen for you to take a look:

v1 (work perfect): http://codepen.io/lindadesu09/pen/AKHbl

v2 (doesn't work): http://codepen.io/lindadesu09/pen/Dumat

Great thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as I can tell, both of those links work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `status` div does not update when you declare it as a global variable is that the global object, `window` in the case of the browser, already has a [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.status) property.

`window.status` is special, it is used to set the status text in the [status bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_bar) at the bottom of the browser. Most modern browsers no longer display a status bar, but the API for dealing with it is still there.

Since the status text can only be a string, when you `var status = document.getElementById("status");` in a global context the DOM node is coerced into a string before it is set as `window.status`. So afterward `window.status` contains the string `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`, not a DOM node.

Setting the `.innerHTML` property of a string does nothing. To fix this, just rename the global `status` variable something else such as `gameStatus`, etc.

Another way to prevent this would be to not use any global variables at all by wrapping all of your code in a [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function () {
  var humanResult = 0;
  var computerResult = 0;
  var status = document.getElementById("status");

  //Click on Rock, Paper, Scissors

  document.getElementById('rock').onclick = clickRock;
  document.getElementById('paper').onclick = clickPaper;
  document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = clickScissors;

  function clickRock() {
    var computer = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1);

    if (computer  == 1) {
      test.innerHTML = "You played rock. The bot played rock you tied. :|"
    };

    if (computer  == 2) {
      computerResult++;
      status.innerHTML = "You played rock. The bot played paper you lose. :(";
    };

    if (computer  == 3) {
      humanResult++;
      status.innerHTML = "You played rock. The bot played scissors you win. :)";
    }

    document.getElementById('humanScore').innerHTML = humanResult;
    document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = computerResult;
  }

  function clickPaper() {
     var computer = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1),

    if (computer  == 1) {
      status.innerHTML = "You played paper. The bot played paper you tied. :|"
    };

    if (computer  == 2) {
      computerResult++;
      status.innerHTML = "You played paper. The bot played scissors you lose. :(";
    };

    if (computer  == 3) {
      humanResult++;
      status.innerHTML = "You played paper. The bot played rock you win. :)";
    }

    document.getElementById('humanScore').innerHTML = humanResult;
    document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = computerResult;
  }

  function clickScissors() {
    var computer = (Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1),

    if (computer  == 1) {
      status.innerHTML = "You played scissors. The bot played scissors you tied. :|"
    };

    if (computer  == 2) {
      computerResult++;
      status.innerHTML = "You played scissors. The bot played rock you lose. :(";
    };

    if (computer  == 3) {
      humanResult++;
      status.innerHTML = "You played scissors. The bot played rock you win. :)";
    }
    document.getElementById('humanScore').innerHTML = humanResult;
    document.getElementById('computerScore').innerHTML = computerResult;
  }
}());
```

I would also try to get rid of some of the redundant code, lots of things could be abstracted into reusable functions. Whenever you find yourself copying and pasting large chunks of code it usually pays off to try to figure out how you could abstract the code into another function, it will save you lots of time and effort on maintenance and adding new features that do roughly the same thing.

I would refactor this code to something like [this (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/hgc4tpg3/):

```
(function () {
  var humanResult = 0,
    computerResult = 0,
    choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
    status = document.getElementById("status"),
    humanScore = document.getElementById('humanScore'),
    computerScore = document.getElementById('computerScore'),
    updateScores = function () {
      humanScore.innerHTML = humanResult;
      computerScore.innerHTML = computerResult;
    },
    makeChoser = function (player) {
      return function () {
        var result,
          computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 );

        if (computer === player) {
          result = 'tied :|';
        } else {
          if (computer < player && !(computer === 0 && player === 2)) {
            result =  'win :)';
            humanResult++;
          } else {
            result = 'lose :(';
            computerResult++;
          }
        }

        status.innerHTML = 'You played ' + choices[player] + '. The bot played ' + choices[computer] + ' you ' + result;

        updateScores();
      };
    };

  document.getElementById('rock').onclick = makeChoser(0);
  document.getElementById('paper').onclick = makeChoser(1);
  document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = makeChoser(2);
}());
```

This is almost half as many lines of code and keeps all the scoring logic in one place, if there was a bug you would only have to troubleshoot and fix one place instead of three.

Comment: Great thanks for your detailed explanation & suggested code, really help me a lot!